# PJSIP throws PJ_ETOOSMALL on register and Invite

Tags: java-native-interface, sip, pjsip

I trying to build an android app with PJSIP and JNI. And it was working ok before. However now im getting the error "Size is too short (PJ_ETOOSMALL) [status=70019]" in PJSIP stacktraces.

Such as ,

```
pjsua_acc.c  .Failed to register with new account setting in modifying account: Size is too short (PJ_ETOOSMALL) [status=70019]

 pjsua_call.c !.Unable to generate Contact header: Size is too short (PJ_ETOOSMALL) [status=70019]
```

The parameters im passing are neither null nor random but working sip endpoints . Any help is appreciated .

PJSIP implemented android logs : https://pastebin.com/s88PEY2C
All sip uri domain names , addresses and ports have been masked

Comment: seems like you are passing null or incorrect params. please paste your debug logs.

Comment: @suren updated the question with debug logs